# Prolog - split a list into lists of lists

Tags: list, split, prolog, swi-prolog

The list to be split is a list of guests that attend a dinner. The dinner has three meals (appetizer, main, and dessert). The result of the type list of lists should be a list for each of the meals with the sub-lists showing the people who eat that meal together.
eg.:

```
Appetizer: [[Tick, Trick, Track],[Tic, Tac, Toe], [Jerry, Larry, Harry]]

Main: [[Tick, Tic, Jerry], [Trick, Tac, Larry],[Track, Toe, Harry]]

Dessert: [[Tick, Tac, Larry], [Trick, Toe, Harry], [Track, Tic, Jerry]]
```

The function I have to code:

```
make_dinner(?Starters, ?Main, ?Dessert, +List_of_Persons, +Group_size):-
```

Group size is the size of the groups (in the example above three)

I don't know how to approach this problem using prolog language. I can easily code this in Java, which I'm really good at. But the recursion and logic here are very confusing to me. There's no "return" argument, no "if" statement", just a bunch of commas :")

My idea was to:

1. find out how many groups I need (depends on group size and list length)
2. fill the appetizer list with the original order of the list. Count it off and split the list after every *group size* position to get the list of lists for an appetizer (the most intuitive way I think)
3. fill the first sub-list of the "main" list with the first element of the list, then the second element of the other sub-lists from the "appetizer" list. Fill the second sub-list with the second element of the first sub-list of "appetizer", then the third element of the next sub-lists in "appetizer", and so on and so forth.

If the number doesn't match (eg. list length 10 but group size 3), I will simply have one group that's smaller. No person eats twice with the same person.

Does my idea work in Prolog? Can I implement that logic?

I don't really know how to approach this task because I'm very new to Prolog. I will have the main function below, then I need a helper_function called get_number_of_groups to know how many elements go into each list. And I have one function to get the size of the list.
How do I make the starters, main, and dessert into a list of lists? I know about recursion but somehow I don't know where to go from here.

```
%make_rudi: main function
%return: starters, main, and dessert; each list of lists
make_rudi(Starters, Main, Dessert, List_of_Persons, Group_size):-
    get_number_of_groups(List_of_Persons, Group_size, Number),

%get_number_of_groups(+List_of_Persons, +Group_size, ?Number)
%return: the number of groups I have for each meal
get_number_of_groups(List_of_Persons, Group_size, Number):-
    Number is list_length(Xs, List_of_Persons)/Group_size.

%list_length(?Xs,+L)
%the length of the list
list_length(Xs,L) :-
list_length(Xs,0,L) .
list_length( \[\]     , L , L ) .
list_length( \[\_|Xs\] , T , L ) :-
T1 is T+1 ,
list_length(Xs,T1,L).
```

Comment: Looks like http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=select/3 will be convenient, to select one from a list and provide the remainder, which are then to be assigned (there's a loop here). Also check out http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3 which may be useful.

Comment: This is the same task: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75083450/prolog-comparing-lists-from-lists-of-lists I hope this helps :)