# Prolog: Comparing Lists from Lists of Lists

Tags: list, prolog, permutation

I am now quite a while trying to figure out what my mistake is, but I am not able to.

Task:
We have to figure out how to find three permutations of a List containing 9 elements in the form of List of Lists. Each List of Lists should contain three sublists, each containing three elements. But no element is allowed to be together with another element in two different sublists.

The following output for the three permutations A, B, C with the given List= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] could be:

```
predicate(A, B, C , [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]).

A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
B = [[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]],
C = [[1,5,9],[2,6,7],[3,4,8]].
```

My Code so far (first my helper predicates) :

To split a list into a List of Lists ( N is always 3 ):

```
split_list(List, N, Splitted_List) :-
    split_helper(List, N, [], Splitted_List).

split_helper([], _, Acc, Acc).

split_helper(List, N, Acc, Splitted_List) :-
    my_append(H, T, List),
    my_length(H, N),
    split_helper(T, N, [H|Acc], Splitted_List).
```

A possible query:

```
split_list([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 3, X).

X = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]].
```

To check wether all sublists  of a List of lists contains at most one same element:

```
max_one_common_element(List1, List2) :-
    max_one_common_element(List1, List2, 0).

max_one_common_element([], _, Count) :-
    Count =< 1.
max_one_common_element([H|T], List2, Count) :-
    (my_member(H, List2) ->
        NewCount is Count + 1,
        max_one_common_element(T, List2, NewCount)
    ;
        max_one_common_element(T, List2, Count)
    ).
```

A possible query:

```
max_one_common_element([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], [[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]).

True.
```

To change order of sublists, for comparing purposes (important later on):

```
swap_lists(List, Result):-
    select(Selected, List, Rest),
    append(Rest, [Selected], Result).
```

A possible query:

```
swap_list([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], X).

X =  [[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,2,3]].
```

My main predicate, which instantiates A, B and C. The one making me issues is C, A and B are properly instantiated.

I was thinking to take all permutations of the input List and check with max_one_common_element/2 wether each sublists  has at most one common element.
Since max_one_common_element/2 is only able to check both lists at the current index ( e.g. [[1,2],[3,4]], [[3,4],[1,2]] would return True, even though it is False) my idea was to change the order of the sublists from A and B two times and check again with C after the first and second change, so all 3 sublists of A and B should be covered.

```
main_predicate(A, B, C, List):- 

    /* instantiates A as the input list but seqmented */

    split_list(List, 3 , A),

    /* instantiates B as a permutation of A, taking every nth element in a sublist*/

    %This part is unimportant since it works properly

    /* instantiates C as a permutation from the input list, test that each Sub-List contains at most one same element */

    permutation(List, Permuted),
    split_list(Permuted, Size, Dessert),
    max_one_common_element(A, C),
    max_one_common_element(A, C),

    /* first swap A and B two times */

    swap_lists(A, A1),
    swap_lists(A1, A2),
    swap_lists(B, B1),
    swap_lists(B1, B2),

    /* Check again with C */

    max_one_common_element(A1, C),
    max_one_common_element(A2, C),
    max_one_common_element(B1, C),
    max_one_common_element(B2, C).
```

When I make a query of:

```
predicate(A, B ,C, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] ).

My output is:
A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] ,
B = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]] ,
C = [[7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]] .
```

Prolog just do not seem to consider every call of max_one_common_element/2. Since deleting some  seem to change the output, but in my mind I have considered all cases and everything should be fine. I also considered changing max_one_common_element/2, but nothing works.
Thank you really much for your help in advance.

Comment: Is unclear - would e.g. `[[1,3,2],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` and `[[2,5,9],[1,6,7],[3,4,8]]` be acceptable? Describe the full range of acceptable permutations.

Comment: @brebs Your example would be acceptable. It is not allowed that any list of the two lists of lists contain more than one common element. 
e.g. [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] and [[3,b,c],[6,e,f],[1,2,g]] -> False, since 1st List of the 1st List of Lists and the 3rd List of the 2nd List of Lists contains both the elements 1 and 2.
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] and [[1,b,c],[4,e,f],[7,h,i]] -> True. 
I hope this makes it clear, if you have any further questions please ask.

Comment: There's many sublists involved here - it would help to clarify if you used e.g. "previous solutions" rather than "sublists" in the problem description. A few examples would also be nice.

Comment: This has been asked recently (the last ~2 months) on here, in the form of diners who must be seated in groups on smaller tables and then the A, B, C results are breakfast, lunch, and dinner, and they must not sit in groups with the same people at each meal. I can't remember if it was answered, but if you can find it, it might help.

Comment: @GuyCoder First of all thanks you for clarifying my question. I considered the Sudoku example that you gave, I could not find anything that would be of real value for my task. My problem is really at applying my at_most_one_common/2 predicate properly. Somehow I am not able to manage to compare the permutations with the both other lists accurately to receive the right output. If I do it manually and one after another it does work.
If I am wrong or have overseen anything pls let me know.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I did manage to find it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74561764/prolog-split-a-list-into-lists-of-lists#comment132520839_74561764), but unfortunately it has not been answered properly. I did put a comment beneath it to point here.

Comment: @GuyCoder Yeah if would be able to generate it perfectly at the first place, but my solution right now creates all permutations and then tests which one fits, as you said. Do you have a tip for directly creating a perfect generate? And to your given answer: Yes this is perfectly correct

Comment: @GuyCoder Thank you a lot for your help, your references were very helpful. Since I have to do this assignment for university, I do not know wether it is a common programming problem with a specific name.

Comment: @GuyCoder Our task was roughly as following: In a running dinner, people are divided into random groups and cook for each other. There are three courses (starter, main, dessert) and each person cooks one course and gets 2 guests. For each course, the groups are reassembled.
Task is to write a predicate that will do the grouping. For each course, we need groups of three people each. Across the aisles, each person should meet as many new people as possible, meaning that they should never share more than one aisle with another person.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controlling the backtracking was interesting (to enforce `comb_available` over all the solution sublists):

```
:- dynamic used/2.

list_perm3(SubLen, L, P) :-
    length(L, Len),
    int_div_lt_plus1(Len, SubLen, SegLen),
    retractall(used(_, _)),
    % Work with instantiated, unique list
    int_list_wrap(L, LN),
    list_perm3_loop(LN, SubLen, SegLen, PN),
    % Map to elements in original list
    perm_lists_wrap(PN, L, P).

int_list_wrap(L, LN) :-
    int_list_wrap_(L, 1, LN).

int_list_wrap_([], _, []).
int_list_wrap_([H|T], I, [i(I, H)|LN]) :-
    I1 is I + 1,
    int_list_wrap_(T, I1, LN).

% Can contain sublists
perm_lists_wrap([], _, []).
perm_lists_wrap([[]|T], L, [[]|P]) :-
    perm_lists_wrap(T, L, P).
perm_lists_wrap([[H|R]|T], L, [E|P]) :-
    % Is a sublist
    perm_lists_wrap([H|R], L, E),
    perm_lists_wrap(T, L, P).
% Using i/2 for first-argument indexing
perm_lists_wrap([i(_, E)|T], L, [E|P]) :-
    perm_lists_wrap(T, L, P).

int_div_lt_plus1(Int, Div, Mod) :-
    divmod(Int, Div, Mod0, Rem),
    (   Rem =:= 0
    ->  Mod is Mod0
    % If doesn't divide cleanly, add 1
    ;   Mod is Mod0 + 1
    ).

list_perm3_loop(L, SubLen, SegLen, P) :-
    % Keeping backtracking to this top-level
    (list_perm3_(L, SubLen, SegLen, P) -> true ; !, fail).
list_perm3_loop(L, SubLen, SegLen, P) :-
    list_perm3_loop(L, SubLen, SegLen, P).

list_perm3_(L, SubLen, SegLen, P) :-
    length(P, SegLen),
    perm3_segments(P, SubLen, L),
    assert_used(P).

assert_used([]).
assert_used([H|T]) :-
    % Assert the used pairs, to prevent reuse
    forall(
        (   select(E1, H, H0),
            member(E2, H0)
        ),
        assert(used(E1, E2))
    ),
    assert_used(T).

perm3_segments([], _, []).
perm3_segments([H|T], SubLen, L) :-
    perm3(L, H, SubLen, R),
    perm3_segments(T, SubLen, R).

perm3(L, P, SubLen, R) :-
    length(L, LLen),
    PLen is min(LLen, SubLen),
    length(P, PLen),
    perm3_(P, L, [], R).

perm3_([], R, _, R).
perm3_([H|T], L, P, R) :-
    select(H, L, L0),
    comb_available(P, H),
    perm3_(T, L0, [H|P], R).

comb_available([], _).
comb_available([H|T], E) :-
    \+ used(E, H),
    comb_available(T, E).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- list_perm3(3, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], P).
P = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] ;
P = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]] ;
P = [[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 7], [3, 4, 8]] ;
P = [[1, 6, 8], [2, 4, 9], [3, 5, 7]] ;
false.
```

To take the first 3:

```
?- once(findnsols(3, P, list_perm3(3, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], P), [A,B,C])).
A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
B = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]],
C = [[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 7], [3, 4, 8]].
```

Example of handling vars and leftover sublists:

```
?- list_perm3(3, [1,2,3,Four,5,6,7,8,9,Ten,Eleven], P).
P = [[1, 2, 3], [Four, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [Ten, Eleven]] ;
P = [[1, Four, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, Ten], [9, Eleven]] ;
P = [[1, 5, 9], [2, Four, Ten], [3, 7, Eleven], [6, 8]] ;
P = [[1, 6, Eleven], [3, Four, 8], [5, 7, Ten], [2, 9]] ;
false.
```

Comment: `numbervars` partly instantiates the variables, which would create 2 problems: Attributed variables (e.g. `dif`, `freeze`), and how to get them back to being variables which could be assigned normal values.

Comment: @brebs your predicate works as expected, the output is perfect. My only last remaining issue is that my task is to instantiate the 3 different Variables A,B,C ( or Starter, Main, Dessert. I do not know how I am able to take the first three outputs of your given predicate and assign them to different Variables?

Comment: @snow_white Use `findnsols` as in my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come up with my own solution:

```
make_dessert(Starter, Main, Dessert, List_of_Persons, Size):-
    permutation(List_of_Persons, Permuted),
    split_list(Permuted, Size, Dessert),
    at_most_one_common(Starter, Dessert),
    at_most_one_common(Main, Dessert).

split_list(List, N, Splitted_List) :-
    split_helper(List, N, [], Splitted_List).

split_helper([], _, Acc, Acc).

split_helper(List, N, Acc, Splitted_List) :-
    append(H, T, List),
    length(H, N),
    split_helper(T, N, [H|Acc], Splitted_List).

at_most_one_common([], _).
at_most_one_common([H|T], List2) :-
    check_list(H, List2),
    at_most_one_common(T, List2).

check_list(_, []).
check_list(X, [H|T]) :-
    intersection(X, H, Z),
    length(Z, L),
    L =< 1,
    check_list(X, T).
```

I forgot to mention that I receive bonus points for keeping the inferences as low as possible. As my program is not as efficient as @brebs 's, I would really appreciate a few tipps from you to lower these. I am maybe also considering starting a new question regarding this case later on.