# Prolog: Reducing Inferences

Tags: list, prolog, permutation

I am trying to **lower the inferences** needed for executing my program in Prolog. My task is exactly the same as in: [Prolog: Comparing Lists from Lists of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75083450/prolog-comparing-lists-from-lists-of-lists) and [Prolog - split a list into lists of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74561764/prolog-split-a-list-into-lists-of-lists#comment132520839_74561764).
My code so far:

```
make_dessert(Starter, Main, Dessert, List_of_Persons, Size):-
    permutation(List_of_Persons, Permuted),
    split_list(Permuted, Size, Dessert),
    at_most_one_common(Starter, Dessert),
    at_most_one_common(Main, Dessert).

split_list(List, N, Splitted_List) :-
    split_helper(List, N, [], Splitted_List).

split_helper([], _, Acc, Acc).

split_helper(List, N, Acc, Splitted_List) :-
    append(H, T, List),
    length(H, N),
    split_helper(T, N, [H|Acc], Splitted_List).

at_most_one_common([], _).
at_most_one_common([H|T], List2) :-
    check_list(H, List2),
    at_most_one_common(T, List2).

check_list(_, []).
check_list(X, [H|T]) :-
    intersection(X, H, Z),
    length(Z, L),
    L =< 1,
    check_list(X, T).
```

Following query generates more than 4,000,000 inferences:

```
make_dessert([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]], D, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 3)).
% 4,380,057 inferences, 0.281 CPU in 0.286 seconds (98% CPU, 15578798 Lips)
D = [[3, 4, 8], [2, 6, 7], [1, 5, 9]].]
```

As all predicates tested by themselves alone are not producing a high number of inferences at all. I am seeing space for improvement in maybe finding the right permutation faster? Or maybe if one permutation is proofed to not fulfil the constraints to stop processing earlier on?
I am grateful for any small improvement.

Comment: I think you either need @Guy Coder's comment on your earlier question "*If however you do a perfect generate then there is no need for a test.*" - generating the correct answers directly without permute. (I don't understand how). Or this is a combinatorial style problem - many possible combinations to churn through, that's `clpfd` territory. I tried to answer the question I referenced using clpfd but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`permutation` creates too many unwanted, erm, permutations. Instead, choose "1 from each segment", to greatly reduce the search space:

```
permute_segments(Segs, Perm) :-
    % Perm will have the same list-of-lists structure
    same_length(Segs, Perm),
    permute_segments_(Perm, Segs).

permute_segments_([], _).
permute_segments_([E|T], Segs) :-
    % Populate each segment of Perm
    select_segments(Segs, E, Segs0),
    permute_segments_(T, Segs0).

select_segments([], [], []).
select_segments([H|T], [E|P], [H0|L]) :-
    % Populate each element of Perm
    select(E, H, H0),
    select_segments(T, P, L).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- permute_segments([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], P).
P = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]] ;
P = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 9], [3, 6, 8]] ;
...
P = [[3, 6, 9], [2, 5, 7], [1, 4, 8]] ;
P = [[3, 6, 9], [2, 5, 8], [1, 4, 7]].
```

To show the efficiency improvement:

```
?- bagof(P, permute_segments([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], P), Ps), length(Ps, Len).
Len = 216.

?- bagof(P, permutation([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], P), Ps), length(Ps, Len).
Len = 362880.
```

Comment: @brebs Thank you very much, this has reduced the necessary inferences by an immense part. But I still can't totally get behind the logic, could you provide some help for understanding this predicate? E.g what is the job of the length/2 predicate, I've never seen it used like this ( only e.g. `length(List, Length)` to receive the length of a list). And I have problems understanding the two recursions of `permute_segments_` and  `select_segments` ?

Comment: And I am also curious about, how it would still work if we have 12 or more persons (always divisible by the Group_Size of 3, e.g. 15 or 18), meaning we would have 4 or more Groups with 3 persons in each. What would be needed to change at the `permute_segments` to make it work with this constraint?

Comment: Use `gtrace` to step through the code, to understand it - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=guitracer  It's iterating through lists of lists, duplicating the list structure. Could use `same_length`, to be more general (which is just a bit slower than using `length`) - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=same_length/2

Comment: @GuyCoder Thank you for your explanation length(Vars,3) now makes total sense for me. I read the article in your link. But I couldn't quite figure out how this helps me with `And I am also curious about, how it would still work if we have 12 or more persons`.

Comment: @snow_white I've tweaked the code, now uses `same_length` for convenience, and the 2nd `length` was unnecessary hence removed.

Answer (score 1):

> I am grateful for any small improvement.

Get rid of `split_list` and `split_helper` and use Prolog unification to split the list into threes:

```
make_dessert(Starter, Main, Dessert, List_of_Persons, _):-
    permutation(List_of_Persons, [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I]),
    Dessert = [[A,B,C], [D,E,F], [G,H,I]],
    at_most_one_common(Starter, Dessert),
    at_most_one_common(Main, Dessert).

at_most_one_common([], _).
at_most_one_common([H|T], List2) :-
    check_list(H, List2),
    at_most_one_common(T, List2).

check_list(_, []).
check_list(X, [H|T]) :-
    intersection(X, H, Z),
    length(Z, L),
    L =< 1,
    check_list(X, T).
```

That drops the inferences from 3.4 Million to 1.06 Million on SWISH:

```
% before
?- time(make_dessert([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]], D, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 3)).
D = [[3, 4, 8], [2, 6, 7], [1, 5, 9]]

3,397,265 inferences, 2.034 CPU in 2.034 seconds (100% CPU, 1670143 Lips)


% after
?- time( make_dessert([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]], D, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 3)).
D = [[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 7], [3, 4, 8]]

1,061,482 inferences, 0.508 CPU in 0.508 seconds (100% CPU, 2091297 Lips)
```

It is possible to use `length/2`, `maplist` and to make the Dessert length dynamic with the input `Size` instead of hard coded to three by three.